# Can i marry with the person whom i have a relationship of three years

Tags: halal-haram, quran

My boyfriend and I have been together for three years and we love each other very much. We acted like we were married and we shared everything, even our bodies. But now he says that we have sinned and that Allah will not bless our marriage if we decide to get married. He says we will be unhappy because we have disobeyed Allah's commands.So will not Allah be pleased with our marriage?

Comment: you both marrying a different person, how is that more good ? I didn't get it.

Comment: I just hope this is not him just tryin to break up with you after baiting you into getting intimate with him